# how to break big lines of code in scala using braces or period

Tags: scala

I have a big line of code in scala-spark of the form f(g(h(x))). Big line because I wanted to execute all 3 in 1 go, but the big line doesn't look very good. How can I break the lines for only 1 variable?

For example, my line is:

```
val transactionsSameDay = (((storeTransactions.filter($"process_date".contains("2018-05-25"))).withColumnRenamed("pcid", "cid")).drop("tc_nbr","store_nbr","trans_ts")
```

What I tried:

```
  val transactionsSameDay = storeTransactions{
                        .filter($"process_date".contains("2018-05-25")
                          .withColumnRenamed("pcid", "cid"))
                          .drop("tc_nbr","store_nbr","trans_ts")
}
```

I just want my code to look good. Thanks

Comment: It sounds like your code works. Is this just an opinion question about aesthetics?

Comment: In `filter{$`, this `{` is a typing mistake?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh oh yes sry, i have edited it.

Comment: @AdamSmith no ! it doesnt work, it is showing error. i want to it to look like this but should also work on spark-terminal

Comment: Your parentheses don't balance, most of them aren't needed, and your example line is not in the form `f(g(h(x)))`.

Comment: can anyone of u write indented code in the answer, please. it would be very helpful

Answer (score 2):

Your single line actually has one extra opening parenthesis in the beginning. If this is a typing mistake and it was originally like following,

```
val transactionsSameDay = ((storeTransactions.filter($"process_date".contains("2018-05-25"))).withColumnRenamed("pcid", "cid")).drop("tc_nbr","store_nbr","trans_ts")
```

then, it can be written like following multiline statement,

```
val transactionsSameDay = storeTransactions
  .filter($"process_date".contains("2018-05-25"))
  .withColumnRenamed("pcid", "cid")
  .drop("tc_nbr","store_nbr","trans_ts")
```

or, it can be broken down into following statement lines,

```
val ds1 = storeTransactions.filter($"process_date".contains("2018-05-25"))
val ds2 = ds1.withColumnRenamed("pcid", "cid")
val transactionsSameDay = ds2.drop("tc_nbr","store_nbr","trans_ts")
```